# How to hide series name and color displaying at the bottom of the highchart?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've highlighted the content to be removed from displaying in my chart

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [legend.enabled](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.enabled). Just add this to your chart:

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/enabled-false/).

Comment: And also one thing, how to hide the x-values(0,4,8,...) values displaying at the x-axis?

Thanks for your legend help @ewolden

Comment: @AkashAashu I'm afraid I can't answer that without seeing your code to understand what is causing them to be there in the first place.